# Remove backlash and double quote using JOLT Transform

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm using Apache Nifi, which is needed to change the current page value using looping.
actually, I've been successful in using several steps to meet the requirement

1. UpdateAttribute : updatePagesValue `${pages:plus(1):toNumber()}`
2. **AttributeToJSON: Merge Pages, Find, Sort, output:**

```json
{
  "pages": "2",
  "find": "[{\"MatchType\":5,\"PropertyName\":\"modifiedon\",\"PropertyValue\":\"2023-04-21\",\"SqlOperation\":1}]",
  "sort": "[{\"SortColumn\":\"modifiedon\",\"SortDirection\":0}]"
}
```

3. ExtractText : ConvertToText
4. ReplaceText : UnescapeJson to Remove backslash
5. ReplaceText : Replace "[ to [
6. ReplaceText : Replace "] to ]
7. ReplaceText : Change "5" to 5

Overall the output meet requirement:

```json
{
  "pages": 2,
  "find": [
    {
      "MatchType": 5,
      "PropertyName": "modifiedon",
      "PropertyValue": "2023-04-19",
      "SqlOperation": 1
    }
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "SortColumn": "modifiedon",
      "SortDirection": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a shortened process, say using `JoltTransform`? From step 2 to step 7.

Thanks

Comment: Please add your base Input before page 2 starts. Do you have a JSON like your output that I can see it at the end of your question? And tried to destruct JSON to get the `page`?

Comment: please cek my flow [link](https://ibb.co/VMc3HLH)

`code
{
    "pages":1,
    "find":[
        {
            "MatchType":5,
            "PropertyName":"modifiedon",
            "PropertyValue":"#{PropertyValue}",
            "SqlOperation":1
        }
    ],
    "sort":[
        {
            "SortColumn":"modifiedon",
            "SortDirection":0
        }
    ]
}
`

Comment: There's no function or method to change the `sort` and `find` string to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following flow:

[image]

**1- `GenerateFlowFile`**

This is just a sample of your input as you mentioned in the comment of your question.

**2- `EvaluateJsonPath`**

Evaluate `pages` from the JSON.

**3- `UpdateAttribute`**

update `pages` value with `${pages:plus(1):toNumber()}`.

**4- `ReplaceText`**

Replace the `pages` to new `pages`.

1. Search Value: `"pages":(.*),`
2. Replacement Value: `"pages": ${pages},`

Comment: OK, I already set unescapeJson in UpdateAttribute, 
the problem occurs while in AttributetoJson ( see point 2 )
`Attribute List : pages,find,sort`
`Destination : flowfile-content`

Comment: @NaviaAng Oh I didn't check processor 2. I'll check it again and update my answer.